# В чем может быть ошибка mysql запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Пытаюсь достать продукт по хешу url

```
SELECT id, url, name, phone, country, email, city, comment, created, total_price FROM orders WHERE url = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Ошибка в phpMyAdmin `#1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' в 'where clause'`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701108/186083

Answer (score 1):

Скобки забыл, без них сравнивает со столбцом.
Правильно:

```
SELECT id, url, name, phone, country, email, city, comment, created, total_price FROM orders WHERE url = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
```

Comment: Вы точно хотите двойные кавычки использовать?

Comment: @Visman, Если ANSI_QUOTES не включен, то тащем-то разницы нет.

Comment: Спасибо понял. Просто обычные кавычки добавил